# How to typehint 'return type or no return' in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting, python-typing

How do I typehint that a function may either return a value or not return anything? What seems to be correct to me is being reported by PyCharm.

```py
def func() -> Optional[Dict]:
```

This results in a warning on the return type when the function does not return anything:

```
Expected to return 'Optional[dict]', got no return
```

But explicitly returning `None` works:

```py
def func() -> Optional[Dict]:
    return None
```

This is all fine with PyCharm. It seems that "no return" is treated differently from `return None` even though to my understanding those two should be the same.

See the image for all three variants:

[image]

What is the correct way to do this? In my use case the function is a class method and its implementations in subclasses will either return `None` or a value. Having to write `return None` in all the subclasses that don't need it is redundant and I want to avoid that.

Comment: "Having to write return None in all the subclasses that don't need it is redundant and I want to avoid that." - Using return hints on a function that never returns anything is also redundant, so why use the hint in the first place? be it as it may, you can just use `-> None` as a type hint and pycharm will agree

Answer (score 2):

> What is the correct way to do this?

IMHO, if your function *sometimes* returns data (which is implied by the `Optional[Dict]`, then when your function returns nothing, explicitly indicating that with `return None` clearly communicates that you didn't forget (remember:  [explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)).

I think PyCharm assumes that if you indicate a (sometimes) not None return type and you have a branch without an explicit return, then you probably made a mistake.  Unfortunately, I cannot back that up with PyCharm documentation.